# Flutter Stopped building for IOS --Error running pod install

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

Everything was working just fine and all of sudden this happned. I tried following

1. Uninstall Cocoapods
2. Install again Update
3. delete pod.lock file
4. upgrade ruby upgrade gem

nothing worked. I tried running other projects too but as soon as I add firebase dependencies I get this error..here

```
Analyzing dependencies
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '6.33.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
[!] Failed to load 'firebase_auth' podspec: 
[!] Invalid `firebase_auth.podspec` file: undefined method `ui' for #<Pod::Specification 
name="firebase_auth">.

 /ios/.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios/firebase_auth.podspec:24
#  -------------------------------------------
#    s.description      = pubspec['description']
>    s.ui.homepage         = pubspec['ui.homepage']
#    s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
#  -------------------------------------------
Error running pod install
```

Comment: Did you try updating cocoapods? 
$ sudo gem install cocoapods

Comment: yes i did...like 20 times..

Comment: I was error that cocapods are not installed or not in valid state please use gem install cocoapods and i did..
thats when i stoped getting that error but now im getting this one.

Comment: try to add lib: `firebase_core: ^0.5.2+1`
before `firebase_auth`
in pubspec.yaml then run `flutter pub get`

Comment: dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: ^0.5.2+1
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.3+1
  firebase_database: ^4.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue of Android studio really. I deleted my project, cloned it from github again and then used Flutter commands in temrinal to run the app on IOS it worked. If I try to run it using android studio it fails still with the same error.